How to use custom ToUnicode maps for text extraction
Tying to use iText7 to extract text from pdf file outputs question marks only:
???????? ??????????
?
???????????????????????? ???????????????????
???????? ????????????????????????????
???????????????????????? ????????????????????????????
?????????????? ?????????????????????
???????????? ????????????????????
??????????
????? ??????????
????????????????????? ???????????????????????????????????
????????????? ??????????
????????????????? ??????????????????????????????????
??????? ???????????????? ????????????????
...

In Adobe and Chrome text can copied from pdf properly. How to extract this text in C#
Code used:
MemoryStream pdfStream = ...
  pdfStream.Position = 0;
  var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
  var reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
  using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
  {
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
  }

According to How to extract text instead of question marks from PDF file  pdf file has bad unicode map for font.
How to force iText or other .NET code pdf text extractor to properly extract text?
Is it possible to pre-process pdf before text extraction to add proper maps or use proper mapping instead mapping to ? character ?

I am not going to download some random pdf from the internet.

.NET is natively Unicode. PDF is not. It's not a document format either, it's a container of print (Postscript) instructions. This isn't about reading Unicode text but finding out what the actual encoding of that PDF file is. Your previous question has no answer so there's no reason to assume that the actual text has anything to do with the font that text is rendered

What does the PDF document contain? I repeat, PDF isn't a text document. It's print instructions. That's why tools require strategies to even guess if some things are consecutive text or not. If the document contains unexpected characters, tools won't be able to read the text. I've seen documents where "tables" flowed vertically instead of horizontally. NOTHING prevents a quirky writer from issuing print commands in a spiral direction. You already got the same answers when you posted an identical question yesterday

You should contact iText support as many .NET libraries can extract the text from the file without problems.

iText has only paid support. I tried pdftotext but text lines appear in wrong order. How to create PDF parser in C# which reads pdf file and writes fixed pdf file? Should https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/Ghostscript.NET used for conversion? Or is it possible to modify iText source code to output corresponding ascii character instead on question mark?

@PanagiotisKanavos iText allows to use text extraction strategies. I modifiled its LocationTextExtraction strategy to sort with rounding to split text to lines: objects are sorted by x,y coordinates before text extraction. In this case output text is the order as seen in PDF viewer.

Hey!
First of all the link to pdf files has been expired. And try to use latest iText version (at 2nd August is 8.0.5), iText fixed a few bugs with text extraction in the recent releases.

I moved to PdfPig. It reads this and other file and has better license.
